# Using ng-show with a controller

Tags: angularjs

I have written an HTML file which consists of a sidebar and a main container which is mapped to a partial. Now, when the partial is loaded based on the config route, I want the sidebar to hide from the browser. For this I tried using `ng-show` on the sidebar div.

Is it the right approach to hide the div from the controller when the routes matches? If so, how do I bind the `ng-show` to the controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I usually do is a structure like this:

```
<nav ng-show="sidebar.show" id="sidebar" ng-controller="sidebarController">
    [...]
</nav>
<div ng-view>
</div>
```

So, the sidebar has his own controller (and it's own scope); then inside the partial's controller you can think about changing the value of `sidebar.show`.
For example:

```
// sidebarController
function sidebarController($rootScope, $scope){
  $rootScope.sidebar = {
    show  : true;
  };
  $scope.sidebar = $rootScope.sidebar;
}

// partialController
app.controller("partialController", function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $rootScope.sidebar.show = false;
});
```

But that's just one way to do it.

**PS:** `ng-show` just hide the element, but it will still be in the DOM; I usually prefer `ng-if` as it doesn't add the element to the DOM.

Comment: How to use ng-if? Should I just replace the ng-show with ng-if?

Comment: ng-if documentation can be found here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf ; you can replace ng-show with ng-if and it should work without problems.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a controller for your sidebar and inject in $scope and $location

```
function sideBarCtrl($scope, $location){}
```

Then I would listen for $routeChangeSuccess on the $scope and based upon the new path, you can determine whether to show/hide your sidebar based upon the path defined on $location

```
$scope.show = true; // or false
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
    // logic here to show/hide based upon $location.path()
    var path = $location.path();
    if (path === 'somePathToShow'){
        $scope.show = true;
    } else if (path === 'somePathToHide') {
        $scope.show = false;
    }
});
```

And per request, your markup would look something like this.

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="SideBarCtrl" ng-show="show">
        <!-- sidebar content -->
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What should be coded on the UI. What should be the directive on the UI to show/hide the div?

Comment: @user883561 I updated my answer with markup and some additional logic to better illustrate the solution

Comment: No problem, hopefully you can use it and keep your $rootScope clean

Comment: For those coming form Google reading this answer: `$scope.$on`works, $ has to be added to the `on` function

Answer (score 1):

Most of the situation we need to hide and show the UI component. In angular js its pretty easy.

Use ng-hide = true -- is the directive, it check the boolean

```html
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyController">
 <div >
 <button name="click" ng-click="click()">Show Donet Chart</button>
 </div>
 <div class="bg-primary" ng-hide="titleEnabled">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>Title
 </div>
 <div ng-hide="divEnabled">
   ------------
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is the controller

```js
function myController($scope){
  $scope.titleEnabled = true;  
  $scope.divEnabled = true;
  
  $scope.click = function(){
     $scope.titleEnabled = false;  
     $scope.divEnabled = false;
    }
}
```